# managing multiple proxies in linux

Tags: proxy, iproute, socks

I use different proxies for different purposes.

- I use shadowsocks proxy for my general purpose web surfing.
- For going to bank websites, I disable proxy.
- For accessing some websites related to my work, I should use an ssh
  tunnel proxy.

So I have a Network Proxy settings GUI opened always and constantly changing between different socks ports when I want to use different websites.

Now I want to define some rules to make proxy switching seamless.
Is there any straightforward way to do it?

Comment: Which GUI do you use? Should the rules be based on target host names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `proxy.pac` (Proxy Auto Configure) file/script and configure that in your browser to direct what proxy (if any) to use when. It would look something like:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var socksProxy = "SOCKS ip.of.sock.proxy:port";
    var workProxy = "PROXY ip.of.work.proxy:port";
    var noProxy = "DIRECT";

    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.mybank.example.com")) return noProxy;
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.work.example.net")) return workProxy;
    if (host == "other.work.example.net"") return workProxy;
    return socksProxy;
}
```

Of course enter the real IPs and ports of the proxies, and use the correct hostnames.

You can specify the path the this file by starting e.g. Google Chrome with `--proxy-pac-url=file:///path/to/proxy.pac`; Chrome on Linux doesn't allow you to directly enter this in the configuration.